# X11 DefaultRootWindow Segfault Only When Program is Run by Systemctl

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, systemctl

I'm new to both Linux and C development, trying to take a screenshot in C with the X11 libs.
If I compile and run my program normally, the screenshot is properly taken with no issues. If I run my program as a service, like

```
sudo systemctl start screenshot
```

The program fails. Both the logs and analyzing the coredump with GDB only say

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

I have set up manual logging in my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv ){
    FILE *fp = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    setvbuf(fp, NULL, _IONBF, 1024);
    fputs("2", fp);
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    fputs("5", fp);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    fputs("6", fp);
```

When run as a service, *log.txt* contains the sequence 25. If run from terminal like ./screenshot, the program terminates normally.

Any hints on finding the cause of the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: This is going to get tricky depending on what and how systemd has set up your windowing system. There are distros that use X and distros that use Wayland and distros that provide a blend of both.. What distro you are using would help.  Additionally, you need to check that `display` is valid by checking its value before using it in `DefaultRootWindow()`. Obviously, if `display == NULL` after the call to `XOpenDisplay(NULL)` -- bad things will happen.

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint, using X. You had it right, if I log whether display is null after calling XOpenDisplay, it's not null when the application is started from terminal, and IS null when started via systemctl. Unfortunately, I still don't know the cause of the different behavior.

Comment: Apparently I'm unable to connect to the display when starting the program as a service, which seems to be a common issue. Haven't found a solution that works yet though.

Answer (score 1):

David pointing out to check whether display is NULL and some searching revealed that the issue is that the program can't open the display when running as a service.

Based on this Question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537628/error-cannot-open-display-on-systemd-service-which-needs-graphical-interface

Setting Environment in the systemd service file as

```
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/<username>/.Xauthority
```

resolved the problem and the service runs without issues.

Comment: Good job chasing that information down. Effort and answer certainly worthy of an upvote.